What's the difference in Visual Studio between amd64_x86 vs x86_amd64
In the build instructions for OpenSSL it gives the options of running:
vcvarsall.bat with x86, x86_amd64, x86_arm, x86_arm64, amd64, amd64_x86;
x86_arm = arm 32-bit;
x64_arm64 = arm 64-bit;

amd64_x86 = 32-bit amd???
amd64 = 64-bit amd?

x86 = x86 32-bit;
x86_amd64 = x64 64-bit;

Why is x86 in AMD and why is AMD in x86, this is so confusing? I know there are plenty of questions about this sort of thing already on the internet, but I can't find what I'm looking for, specifically the difference between x86_amd64 and amd64_x86.

x86_amd64 -> x86_x64 -> [TARGET_ARCH=x64, HOST_ARCH=x86] so you build x64 binary on x86 host. visa versa - amd64_x86 -> x64_x86 -> [TARGET_ARCH=x86, HOST_ARCH=x64] - you build x86 binary on x64 host.

@RbMm And I found out I should be using amd64 for just x64, where the hell does the AMD come into it? The architecture is x86, but 64-bit, and Intel.

in windows usually amd64 and x64 mean the same

@Zebrafish AMD was the first one to introduce IA32e, hence the name.
